# Change the log level at runtime in Kura OSGi console

Tags: osgi, kura

From version 4 of Eclipse Kura the "setkuraloglevel" command is removed.
How do you get to change the log level at runtime now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that since Kura 4 is by editing `/opt/eclipse/kura/log/log4j.xml` file. You can set the logging levels from there and also define some specific packages to be logged.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation. IMO, it is a pity as the previously available approach was certainly easier and faster.